# Rails public folder reroute to controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes

So I followed this tutorial on DigitalOcean to deploying rails server through passenger, not sure if I did it correctly as my server is on CentOS 7.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Basically my question is, if I use http conf to redirect incoming traffic to the app's public folder (/var/www/html/myapp/public), is there a way to redirect from the public folder to say an index of a controller?

I've tried editing the root routes in the routes file but I'm still hitting the default Apache start up page.
root 'testcontroller#index' (does not work.)

Please let me know if you need more info.
Thanks!

-Edit 4/22/15-
Pasting my routes.rb content below

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :ip_logs

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'ip_logs#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

I have created a scaffold called ip_logs. If I'm running rails server using `rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80` it will redirect to the index page for ip_logs. Just wanted to know how I can do the same using http conf to redirect the incoming traffic from /public to the index page for a particular controller.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `routes.rb` or the output `rake routes`?

Comment: Added my routes.rb file content as requested. I'll go back home and try reroute root again.

Comment: You have rails routing set up to display the `index` action for the `ip_logs` controller at your root.  You shouldn't need to do anything in your Apache configuration file to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah it works when I run rails server with using the rails server command. But I was looking up tutorials on how I can run a rails server in production (using Apache/Passenger?) which led me to the DigitalOcean tutorial which suggested that I configure Apache to point to the '/public' folder, but I end up with the default Apache test page when I try to load the app.

I'm still relatively new to Rails but when running a rails server in production, do you normally use the 'rails server' command and set it to run as a daemon? Thank again for taking time to answer my post. Appreciate it.

Comment: I think it would be `rails server -e production` but I deploy using Heroku so I am not sure.